# Looking for NaN values in a specific column in df

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a function that if it finds any NaN value inside a specific column to display "ERROR"

I tried this

```
pd.isna(df1['ColumnNme'])
```

but it gives me a list of boleans, so i cant make the function:

```
if pd.isna(result['Region'])== True:
    print('ERROR')
```

Comment: `pd.isna(df1['ColumnNme']).any()`

Comment: when in doubt, consult the wise elder (AKA, a google search)